# Chrome = 117.0.5938.150 | ChromeDriver = 117.0.5938.149 - I can't run a program in VBA because of this. I'm not finding the version 150 of driver

Tags: vba, google-chrome, webdriver

Chrome = 117.0.5938.150 | ChromeDriver = 117.0.5938.149 - I can't run a program in VBA because of this. I'm not finding the version 117.0.5938.150 of chromedriver

I'm searching of 117.0.5938.150 chromedriver

Can someone help me?

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to download the file.
it's work for me
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/